# Permittivity of air's dependence on frequency

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric

It is known that for most materials, permittivity is a function of frequency, and thus the value of permittivity can have a vast variation. However, in the case of air, it is often considered $\approx$ 1.

What is the physical/mathematical reason to this lack of effect on the permittivity of air by frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[The dielectric constant (ε′- real part) decreases rapidly with the increase in frequency. This decrease is due to the reduction of space charge polarization effect](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2018/ra/c8ra00794b)" (opposite charges separation in space becomes weaker).

The molecular density of air is much less than other condensed matter materials so *space charge polarization effect* is much weaker therefore the frequency span has little to practically no affect to the air's dielectricity.